# Calling a console application (.exe) file using Task Scheduler is returning the following error "0x41301"

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks

I have a console application which uses some SharePoint dll libraries, to execute a background jobs.

Now I can manually run the console application without any problem. but when I schedule its execution using windows 2008 R2 Task Scheduler, I got the following error:

```
0x41301
```

Here is how the action looks like:

[image]

And I have the following text inside the Add arguments:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\batchfiles\ConsoleApplication1.exe
```

Can anyone advise why I am getting this error?

Comment: 0x41301 = SCHED_S_TASK_RUNNING = The task is currently running

Comment: @magicandre1981 but it will stay for long time,, while if I manually run the console application it will ends after 20 seconds...

Comment: I have no idea. I only checked the Headers of the SDK to see what the error means